# How to get name from id of ForeignKey in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

**Issue**

When I call {{cats}} I'm getting an id, How can I get the category name in the same place?

**My Html File**

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load static %}

    {% block title %}
    Blogue | {{cats}}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
```

**Views.py**

```
    def CategoryView(request, cats):
        category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cats)
        return render(request, 'categories.html', {'cats':cats.title(),'category_posts':category_posts})
```

**Urls.py**

```
   urlpatterns = [
       .........
       path('category/<str:cats>/', CategoryView, name='category-list'),
   ]
```

**Models.py**

```
      class Category(models.Model):
          name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

          def __str__(self):
              return self.name

          def get_absolute_url(self):
              return reverse('home')

      class Post(models.Model):
          title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
          author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
          body = models.TextField()
          post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
          category = models.ForeignKey(Category ,max_length=60 ,default='Others', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name= 'cats')

          def __str__(self):
              return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)

          def get_absolute_url(self):
              return reverse('article-detail', args=(str(self.id)))
```

I've tried changing using the category class but not getting the correct output yet, and also tried using 'categories_post' but that too didn't help.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
Post.objects.filter(category__name=cats)
```

One can use double underscores (`__`) to look "*through*" relations.

You can for example visit `/category/programming/` will list the `Post`s for the `programming` category. You can define an absolute rul for a `Category` with:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category-list', kwargs={'cats': self.name})
```

It might however make sense to work with a [**`SlugField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#slugfield), not a `CharField` to filter on a category.

For links you should work with:

```
<a href="{% url 'category-list' post.category.name %}">
```

Comment: This helped me to get the proper URL like  /category/programming listed me with Posts for Programming but when redirecting button is clicked within the webpage it still takes me to the old URL i.e category/8    This is my urls.py    path('category/<str:cats>/', CategoryView, name='category-list')

Comment: @not-a-great-programmer: where do you *render* the links? Edit the question with the part of the template where you render the links to the articles of a category.

Comment: <a href="{% url 'category-list' post.category.id %}">  this is how I link it, If that's what you're asking?

Comment: @not-a-great-programmer: you should work with `post.category.name` instead of `post.category.id`. See edit.

Comment: Still getting the same error, while clicking the redirecting hyperlink. Redirected to the old location i.e. category/8 instead of category/programming/

Comment: @not-a-great-programmer: you should replace all the links with the new `post.category.name`, and restart the webserver.

Comment: Rookie Mistake. Thanks a lot, Man. Appreciate the help!